# Inheriting a C# class that has only a private constructor

Tags: f#, xmlunit-2

I'd like to subclass the XMLUnit.NET [`CompareConstraint`](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net/blob/40d167f78e7b9e6e78720ff1d3d15b59bfe155dd/src/main/net-constraints-nunit3/CompareConstraint.cs) class in my F# code.

However, that class only has a single private constructor. If I try to inherit it, I get this compile error:

`This 'inherit' declaration specifies the inherited type but no arguments. Consider supplying arguments, e.g. 'inherit BaseType(args)'.`

Is there any way to inherit a class without a public constructor in F#?

Comment: I would add that preventing inheritance is the whole point of having a private constructor. Whoever made that class specificlly didn't want you to inherit from it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. @ildjarn: if you want to put your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an F# limitation – it is not possible to inherit from a type with only private constructors in *any* .NET language.